# CakePHP - Missing controller view - $_SESSION not available

Tags: cakephp

We are experiencing an issue when an invalid url is passed to cake. This loads the missing_controller.ctp view correctly but $_SESSION variable is empty.

We have tested this on 1.3 and 2.0 and in both version $_SESSION is empty when the missing_controller view is rendered.

Is this done on purpose?

Thanks

Regards
Gabriel

Answer (score 4):

Did you imported the Session component in Controller? Like this:

```
<?php
class MissingController extends AppController{
var $components = array('Session');
var $helpers = array('Session');
}
```

Try to access the data in $_SESSION with `$this->Session->read('This.That');`

Comment: exactly - $_SESSION might empty if no call has been made to the session yet through proper channels - $this->Session->read()